# How can I get the character code using only bash, without xdd?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

No use perl, python, and similar.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `printf`, a bash builtin: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071

If you want the ASCII code of a character in hex:

```
function ord {
  printf %x "'$1"
}

ord A # 41
ord 0 # 30
```

The use of the single leading quote is explained here:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html

> If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be
>   the numeric value in the underlying codeset of the character following the
>   single-quote or double-quote.

Comment: @Steven Penny what is the point in changing the answer completely without any proper explanation?

Comment: @fedorqui Unicode characters use hex code points, not sure why anyone would want decimal http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements

Comment: @StevenPenny Then it would be interesting to indicate so somewhere.

Comment: The original version of this answer explained that to get the decimal representation instead of hex, you can use %d instead of %x. I'm not sure why that was removed, but some readers might find it helpful.

Comment: for print to new line in bash terminal `function ord {   printf  "%x\n" "'$1"; }`